# Parse: [Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.2)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm struggling with saving a PFObject: `trip` is a property on a `UIViewController`, it is of type `UNTrip` a subclass of `PFObject`. My App downloads a trip created by another user. As soon as I change a property on this trip and then try to save it with `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` I get the error "object not found". I made sure that both sending and receiving users have write access, which I checked in the Parse console. I also tried with public write access to no avail, so that's apparently not the issue.

The `objectId` is not touched, so that can't be the issue either.

This is what the console shows:

> (PFObject) Parse.PFObject = {
>    NSObject = {
>      isa = Unter.UNTrip
>    }
>    dirty = false
>    operationSetQueue = 0x0000000171651f10 "1 value"
>    estimatedData = 0x0000000171653290 5 key/value pairs
>    lock = 0x00000001702157c0
>    hasBeenFetched = true
>     _dataAvailability = 0x0000000171651f40 4 key/value pairs
>     _isDeleted = false
>     _deletingEventually = 0
>     serverData = 0x0000000171651a90 5 key/value pairs
>     hashedObjectsCache = 0x00000001716524b0 2 key/value pairs
>     updatedAt = 0x0000000170215810 2015-05-17 14:23:29 UTC
>     createdAt = 0x0000000170215800 2015-05-17 14:23:29 UTC
>     localId = nil
>     objectId = 0x000000017063e860 "M4WqMOFtMn"
>     parseClassName = "UNTrip"
>     createdAsPointer = true
>     _eventuallyTaskQueue = 0x000000017063dbc0
>     saveDelegate = nil
>     taskQueue = 0x000000017063db40
>   }

UNTrip class:
`class UNTrip: PFObject, PFSubclassing, Printable{`

The trip is successfully saved by user A in the cloud, setting write access for  both users A and B (`respondingUser`):

```
  func saveTripToCloud(trip: UNTrip){
// Find user
let userQuery = PFUser.query()
userQuery?.whereKey("email", equalTo: trip.respondingUser!.email)
userQuery?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let respondingUser = object as? PFUser {
      println("First user: \(respondingUser.username)")
      trip.ACL?.setWriteAccess(true, forUser: respondingUser)
      trip.ACL?.setWriteAccess(true, forUser: PFUser.currentUser()!)

      trip.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

User B successfully retrieves the trip from the cloud after receiving a push with the objectId (includeKey to also retrieve other stored PFObjects):

```
    if let objectId = userInfo["objectId"] as? String {
  var query = PFQuery(className: "UNTrip")
  query.includeKey("requestingUser")
  query.includeKey("respondingUser")
  query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId, block: { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

User B then changes one of the properties on trip (use of self because it's done in a completion block):

`self.trip?.respondingUser?.travelTime = travelTime`

User B is then UNsuccessful in trying to save trip back to the cloud via:

`trip?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succes:Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in`

success: false, error: object not found

Can somebody shed some light?

Comment: need to see the code

Answer (score 1):

Phew, finally solved this one.

When User B receives a trip, it changes the property `trip.respondingUser.travelTime`. `respondingUser` is another `PFObject` subclass instance created by User A. I forgot to give User B write access to that `PFObject` subclass instance before sending it over to User B by including this line of code: `trip.respondingUser?.ACL?.setWriteAccess(true, forUser: respondingUser)` where respondingUser is a `PFUser` instance referring to User B, the user that receives the `trip`.

Problem solved, thanks for having a look.